# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tickets_per_person' referenced before assignment but 'tickets_per_person' assigned as a global variable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, thonny

I keep getting this error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tickets_per_person' referenced
>   before assignment.

However I have assigned the variable `tickets_per_person` as a global variable at the top of my code so i do not understand why it isn't being recognized.

The full function is:

```py
def date_price_increase() :
    if 'July' or 'August' or 'September' in full_date :
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person * 1.15
    elif 'February' or 'October' or 'November'in full_date :
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person * 0.95
    else :
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person
```

Assigning the global variable :

```py
global tickets_per_person
tickets_per_person = 0
```

The traceback is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"C:\Users\samue\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", 
line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\samue\OneDrive - The Becket 
School\Airport_Tkinters_GUI_29.12.18.py", line 485, in cost
    date_price_increase()
  File "C:\Users\samue\OneDrive - The Becket 
School\Airport_Tkinters_GUI_29.12.18.py", line 325, in date_price_increase
   tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person * 1.15
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tickets_per_person' referenced before 
   assignment
```

Comment: You need to declare the variable global inside the function. When you assign to it inside the function, it creates a local variable with the same name unless you have declared it global inside the function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function).

Comment: you have to use `global tickets_per_person` inside `def date_price_increase():` to inform function that you want to assign to global variable, not to local one. There is no need to use word `global` outside functions because all variables created outside functions are global.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `global tickets_per_person` inside `def date_price_increase():` to inform function that you want to use global variable `tickets_per_person` instead of  local one.

```
def date_price_increase() :

    global tickets_per_person

    if 'July' or 'August' or 'September' in full_date :
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person * 1.15
    elif 'February' or 'October' or 'November'in full_date :
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person * 0.95
    else :
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person
```

---

There is no need to use word `global` outside functions because all variables created outside functions are global.

---

**EDIT:** you should create normal function with parameters and `return`. It is prefered method.

```
def date_price_increase(tickets_per_person, full_date):

    if 'July' or 'August' or 'September' in full_date:
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person * 1.15
    elif 'February' or 'October' or 'November'in full_date:
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person * 0.95
    else:
        tickets_per_person = tickets_per_person   

    return tickets_per_person
```

and run

```
tickets_per_person = date_price_increase(tickets_per_person, full_date)
```

Comment: this didnt seem to work as i have referenced it in multiple functions so I tried to place it outside the function at the top. I tried your method but this error came up :UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tickets_per_person' referenced before assignment

Comment: you can't get this error if you have `global tickets_per_person` inside function. OR maybe you use this variable in another function - then you have to use `global tickets_per_person` in another function too. In traceback you should see in which function you have problem. You may have this error also if you have typo in variable - so it uses different variable with `global`.

Comment: so i need to put    'global tickets_per_person'   inside every function

Comment: you have to use `'global tickets_per_person` in every function where you use `tickets_per_person`. Or create normal function with parameters `def date_price_increase(tickets_per_person, full_date):` and with result `return tickets_per_person` and run as `tickets_per_person = date_price_increase(tickets_per_person, full_date)`